# Finding tweet id from parsed html page

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, tweets

I am trying to get tweet id from the parsed HTML. Here is my code:

```
tweet_ids = []
stat = statnum_parser(page_soup)
name = stat["Full_Name"]
print(page_soup.select("div.tweet"))
for tweet in page_soup.select("div.tweet"):   # doesn't work properly
    if tweet['data-name'] == name:
        tweet_ids.append(tweet['data-tweet-id'])
```

The if condition checks if the tweet is not retweeted. The for loop does not work properly. Can someone help me?

## I am using Selenium, BeautifulSoup

Comment: what about the `for`-loop does not work properly? why aren't you using [tweepy](http://www.tweepy.org/)?

Comment: For loop works properly. For some of the twitter profiles, the code works well. For other, it does not. I did not use tweepy because I have to do the project asap. And I am there almost.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. The problem was not using properly selenium with BeautifulSoup. Here is the code to get properly the HTML content of static website:

```
    import selenium as webdriver
    path_to_chrome_driver="path_to_your_chrome_driver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chrome_driver)
    driver.base_url = "URL of the website"
    driver.get(driver.base_url)
```